# Android Marshmallow 6.0.1, how do I check if a file is a media one from content URI?

Tags: android, share, media, android-6.0-marshmallow

When I share a picture from gallery, in my activity that receives the intent I get the content URI but uri.getAuthority() returns "0@media". The trouble is that even for a PDF, it returns the same value for getAuthority(). How do I distinguish between a media file and another file (eg: PDF) in my activity ?

Am facing this issue only in MM 6.0.1, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(pass_your_URI));
```

So, if the selected file is an image of `jpeg` extension, the `type` returns `jpeg`. However, just invoking `cR.getType(pass_your_URI)` will return  `mime/jpeg` which you can also use to differentiate media type out of URI.